# Python: Remove strings from list that doesn't contain specific string but not exact match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings

**e.g:**

```
kw_list = 
       ['facebook',
        'google',
        'bank',
        'bank cd rates', 
        'forever 21', 
        'bank rates',
        'bank of america mortgage rates',
        'bank exchange rates']
```

and I have a string

e.g:

```
keyword = 'bank rates'
```

I want to be able to remove anything from the list that doesn't contain my string in this case `bank rates`. But I don't want to remove it as an exact match.

So after cleaning the list it would look something like this:

```
kw_list = [
        'bank cd rates', 
        'bank rates',
        'bank of america mortgage rates',
        'bank exchange rates']
```

I tried using:

```
new_kws = []
     for i in kw_list:
                if keyword in i:
                    new_kws.append(i)
                    print('It has the word',keyword , '--->' ,i)
                else:
                    print('it doesnt have the word ---> ', i)
```

But this only looks for the exact match of 'bank rates' and in the following example this code will remove strings like `bank cd rates`, `bank of america mortgage rates` and `bank exchange rates'` So it will leave the list as:

```
   kw_list = [
            'bank rates',
           ]
```

What would be the best way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Regexp `bank .* rates`? (Module `re` to handle regexps in python)

Comment: When looping through the keywords in your list, try to to `.split()` them. This will create a list of each separate word in your keyword and then you can check word by word. Example: `"bank rates".split() = ['bank', 'rates']`. Now you can check if both words exist in the other string and also if it's exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
new_list = [word for word in kw_list if all(val in word for val in keyword.split(' '))]
```

`OUTPUT`

```
['bank cd rates', 'bank rates', 'bank of america mortgage rates', 'bank exchange rates']
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I needed is working as expected.

Comment: could you explain what this code is doing?

Comment: Yeah sure, here we are using list comprehension. In this part `word for word in kw_list` you iterate over your list and then in this part `keyword.split(' ')` you first split your key word and then `all()` checks whether all words in keywords exist in the word from list. `all()` will return `True` if all of the words in your keyword exist in your word from list

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like this, by splitting and checking each word in list:

```
def check_keyword(kw_string, kw_split):
    word_list = kw_string.split(' ')
    for word in kw_split:
        if word not in word_list:
            return False
    return True
    
kw_list = ['facebook',
        'google',
        'bank',
        'bank cd rates', 
        'forever 21', 
        'bank rates',
        'bank of america mortgage rates',
        'bank exchange rates']
        
        
keyword = 'bank rates'
kw_split = keyword.split(' ')

result = [x for x in kw_list if check_keyword(x, kw_split)]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same code as yours except one line of condition is changed, this will work as per your expectation

```py
    kw_list = [
            'bank cd rates',
            'bank rates',
            'bank of america mortgage rates',
            'bank exchange rates']
    keyword = 'bank rates'
    new_kws = []
    for i in kw_list:
        if "bank" in i and "rates" in i:#changed condition
            new_kws.append(i)
            print('It has the word',keyword , '--->' ,i)
        else:
            print('it doesnt have the word ---> ', i)
    print(new_kws)
```